# English ditransitive verb phares in CKY algorithm

Tags: parsing

I was pondering about English ditransitive verb phrases. Say we have the following: *Sofia the candle*. I can assume the phrase structure VP -> V NP NP, which is not a binary production.

Any clue, how can we parse this ditransitive with the CKY algorithm?

Comment: I don't follow you. Your example is not ditransitive.

Comment: @BillJ Yes it is: e.g. *Peter gave Sofia the candle.* OP just didn't provide the entire sentence, but only the critical part within the VP.

Comment: @lemontree I'm well aware what a ditransitive clause is. What possible reason could there be for omitting the verb?